# Fine Uploader: File is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

i'm trying to integrate "Fine Uploader" into my own CMS.  After a successful upload, I remove the uploader to display a link to the file with a delete-button besides it. The problem is, that every upload fails, if the time period after the last upload is too short(less than ~30s). The problem only occurs on web-servers, not on my local one.

```
uploader = $('.file-uploader').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: fullpath+'/detailseite/upload/tmp'
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: extensions
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    text: {
        uploadButton: '<div class="btn button-white">File hochladen</div>'
    },
    multiple: false
}).on('progress', function (id, fileName, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
    $('.new_elements:not(.disabled),.update_elements:not(.disabled)').addClass('disabled');

}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success){
        //uploader.fineUploader('reset');
        file_name = responseJSON.name;
        $('.file-uploader').html('<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo PATH; ?>files/tmp/'+file_name+'" ><b>'+file_name+'</b></a><input type="hidden" name="name" value="'+file_name+'" />');
        $('.file-uploader').append('<a href="<?php echo $full_path; ?>/contentmanagement/file_loeschen/tmp/'+file_name+'/dokument" class="delete_imageu"></a>');
        $('.new_elements,.update_elements').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});

$(document).off('click','.'+element_id+' a.delete_imageu');
$(document).on('click','.'+element_id+' a.delete_imageu', function()
{
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            $('.'+element_id).children().remove();
            $('.'+element_id).html('<div class="file-uploader" id="<?php echo $element_id; ?>"></div>');
            name = element_id;
            //uploader.fineUploader('reset');
            uploader = $('.'+element_id+' .file-uploader').fineUploader({
                request: {
                    endpoint: fullpath+'/detailseite/upload/tmp'
                },
                validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: extensions
                },
                retry: {
                    enableAuto: true
                },
                text: {
                    uploadButton: '<div class="btn button-white">File hochladen</div>'
                },
                debug: true,
                multiple: false
            }).on('progress', function (id, fileName, uploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
                $('.new_elements:not(.disabled),.update_elements:not(.disabled)').addClass('disabled');

            }).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON){
                if (responseJSON.success){
                    file_name = responseJSON.name;
                    $(this).html('<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo PATH; ?>files/tmp/'+file_name+'" ><b>'+file_name+'</b></a><input type="hidden" name="name" value="'+file_name+'" />');
                    $(this).append('<a href="<?php echo $full_path; ?>/contentmanagement/file_loeschen/tmp/'+file_name+'/dokument" class="delete_imageu"></a>');
                    $('.new_elements,.update_elements').removeClass('disabled');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Debug output:

```
[FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs... jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] Sending upload request for 1 jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 1 jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] responseText = {"error":"File is empty"} jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] Waiting 5 seconds before retrying zztailtoddle_lo.mp3... jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] Retrying zztailtoddle_lo.mp3... jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] Sending upload request for 1 jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 1 jquery.fineuploader-3.5.0.min.js:4
[FineUploader] responseText = {"success":true,"name":"zztailtoddle_lo38.mp3","type":"mp3"}
```

Server-side Code

```
class qqFileUploader {
private $allowedExtensions = array();
private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
private $file;

function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){
    $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

    $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

    $this->checkServerSettings();

    if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
        $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
    } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
        $this->file = new qqUploadedFileForm();
    } else {
        $this->file = false;
    }
}

private function checkServerSettings(){
    $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));

    if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
        $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';
        die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size'}");
    }
}

private function toBytes($str){
    $val = trim($str);
    $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        case 'g': $val *= 1024;
        case 'm': $val *= 1024;
        case 'k': $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $val;
}

/**
 * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
 */
function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = false,$thumbnail = false,$width = null,$height = null){

    if (!$this->file){
        return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
    }

    $size = $this->file->getSize();

    if ($size == 0) {
        return array('error' => 'File is empty');
    }

    if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
        return array('error' => 'File is too large');
    }

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
    $filename = normalize_string($pathinfo['filename']);

    $ext = $pathinfo['extension'];

    if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
        $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
        return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
    }

    if(!$replaceOldFile){
        /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
        while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
            $filename .= rand(10, 99);
        }
    }

       if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory.$filename.'.'.$ext)){

       $src =  $uploadDirectory.$filename.'.' . $ext;


        return array('success'=> true,'name' => $filename. '.' .$ext,'type' => $ext);
    } else {
        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is there some systematic difference between files for which the upload succeeds and files for which it fails, like the file size or file type, or even the file name?

Comment: Could you then please post the debug output generated by the script and the part of the server-side script that handles the uploaded file? Thanks.

Comment: I added the debug output in my question, If the server-side script is be the problem, why does the upload work most of the time ?

Comment: Which browser?  What does your server side code look like?  Uploads that sometimes work does not mean that the problem is not server side.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome. I've added the server-side code

Comment: Is this happening in any other browsers, such as Firefox?  Can you have a look at the request in the network tab in FF and Chrome for one of these failing files and verify that the Content-Length is non-zero and some data is apparently present in the file multipart boundary?  You can paste the contents of the network tab for a failing file, if you want.

Comment: Yes it's happening in Firefox too. The content-length is non-zero. does that mean, that my server side code could cause the problem ?

Comment: Is the content-length close to the expected file size?  Note that the content-length will include the file and the space needed to store all parameters as well.

Comment: The content-length of the request which isn't working is the same as the length of the working one.

Comment: Then this does sound like an issue caused by something server-side.  Perhaps even a router, firewall, or proxy is messing with the request in some cases?  I actually had a similar issue at my workplace at one point.  An appliance was stripping out the file in some instances.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comments section, it does seem like you are experiencing some issues server-side.  Perhaps something is interfering with the request?  I had a similar issue at my workplace at one point.  A network appliance was removing the file in the request (or perhaps even more than that, I don't recall) in some cases.  The file would succeed on auto-retry though.  I suppose its also possible that something isn't quite right in your PHP request handler as well.  You will likely need to dig a bit deeper.  This may involve inspecting the request as it hits your PHP handler and comparing it with the request according to either Chrome/Firebug's network tab or a proxy (such as Charles).  If the requests do not match up, then something is intercepting the request and messing with it.  If they do match up, and the request looks ok, then perhaps there is an issue in your PHP code.

Comment: Aaah, now i've found out something very interesting ! It's about the time between the single uploads. If i wait 30 seconds after each upload, the error never Occurs. What could cause this ?

Comment: ... A server-misconfiguration ?

Comment: Hard to say.  You are in the only position to verify this as you have a good understanding of your server environment and code, and I do not.