# Fine-Uploader aborting upload with 'File is empty' error

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I'm using non-jQuery dependent FineUploader with the PHP example error-reporting script to upload a file. Chunking and resuming are turned on. All handling is from the PHP example scripts without any modifications.

Works successfully on test files of up to ~90mb, however when attempting to upload a file of 329mb, the upload begins but then aborts with the 'File is empty' error.

I can see from my chunk folder that approximately 77mb of the file was uploaded before the error. Attempts to resume do not work and do not increase the size of the chunk directory.

Environment: LAMP, Centos 6.3.

`post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` both set to 2048M in php.ini.

Any indiciation as to the cause of this? Happy to provide additional information.

Uploader code:

```
<div id="failed-fine-uploader"></div>

<script>
function createUploader() {
var faileduploader = new qq.FineUploader({
element: document.getElementById('failed-fine-uploader'),
request: {
    endpoint: 'example.php'
},
chunking: {
      enabled: true
},
resume: {
      enabled: true
},
failedUploadTextDisplay: {
    mode: 'custom',
    maxChars: 40,
    responseProperty: 'error',
    enableTooltip: true
}
}); 
}
window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
```

EDIT: Console info:

```
[17:31:09.314] [FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs...
[17:31:09.315] [FineUploader] Resuming CentOS-6.3-x86_64-minimal.iso at partition index 40
[17:31:09.316] [FineUploader] Sending chunked upload request for item 4: bytes 80000001-82000000 of 346011648
[17:31:09.504] [FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 4
[17:31:09.504] [FineUploader] responseText = {"error":"File is empty.","uploadName":null}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276284/fine-uploader-file-is-empty.  Have you looked at the raw request and checked the Content-Length header value when this happens?

Comment: I've just added the console data at the point it fails. Unlike the question linked (which I've read), this is non-ajax, and fails 100% of the time.

Comment: Additionally: If I turn OFF chunking, the file upload progress bar goes to 100%, and *then* throws the 'File is empty' error.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I didn't download the ajax-version.

Comment: Still don't know what you are talking about.  There is no "non-ajax version".  Did you mean you downloaded the no-dependency version, as opposed to the jQuery plug-in version?

Comment: Sorry yes, that's what I mean. Long day xD

Comment: According to the logs, FU is attempt to resume a failed or interrupted upload.  Is your code accounting for that properly?  I can't recall if the example PHP code handles resumes.  Can you turn that off, try a new large file, and see what happens?

Comment: I've turned off chunking and resumes, removed the cookie, and the chunk directory and tried again. It reaches 100%, and then throws the same error.

Comment: Please show the raw request properties for this failing file.

Comment: Have a look at the network tab in Chrome's developer tools, for example.

Comment: This definitely appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276284/fine-uploader-file-is-empty.

Comment: That question has no solution either - there you said 'Must be some problem with your server-side set-up', which isn't exactly helpful, no offense.

Comment: Update: The upload was using https. If I turn https off I get a 'Could not save the uploaded file' error. In my upload directory, the file is there with size 0.

Comment: Why would this work just fine for small files but not large ones? The limits in PHP are set to 2gb and I'm only trying a 300mb file.

Comment: I've asked you for raw request information several times.  The fact that you do not seem to know what this means or how to do this suggests you should enlist the help of a more experienced developer at your organization who is also familiar with your setup.  There is not much I can do without access to this kind on info.  Quite frankly, if the raw request looks good, then the issue is with your environment, just like the case I referenced.  This is something you should be familiar with and should be able to troubleshoot.  I'm not sure what you expect me or anyone else to do here.

Comment: 'Raw request' could mean lots of things, which is why I was asking. Do you mean you want the *http header*? Eitherway, I'll work it out myself and post back a self-answer to this question that will be useful to others.

Comment: Raw request means all of the elements that make up the request, such as headers and payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are experiencing this (rather unhelpful) error, it could be a number of things, so I'd advise checking them all. This answer is in the context of 'very large' files where this error seems to occur.

In your php.ini, check to ensure that:

`post_max_size` is set high enough to cover the file size (max 2G)

`upload_max_filesize` is set high enough to cover the file size (max 2G)

That `post_max_size` is larger than `upload_max_filesize` (as recommended by http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), and that `memory_limit` is larger than `post_max_size`. Any of these factors could result in the `$_FILES` superglobal returning as empty, and erroring out the upload.

Other things to try in php.ini:

That `max_execution_time` is increased to take in to account the duration of the upload (large files typically take longer than the default of 30), and `max_input_time` is also increased accordingly.

You may also need to modify your httpd.conf with the `LimitRequestBody` directive as this may be overriding anything specified in php.ini. This is specified in bytes and can be specified either directly in httpd.conf or in a .htaccess file (assuming you have Override priviliges). You can also specify this on a per-directory basis (for security) as follows.

```
<Directory "/var/www/myuploaddir/">
        LimitRequestBody 1073741824
</Directory>
```

Finally, also ensure that you have sufficient temporary and non-temporary storage for the file being uploaded. The package does not catch 'out of space' errors.

Comment: Great info here.  The PHP example was not provided by myself as I am not a PHP developer.  What specific issue ended up causing you grief?

Comment: In the end I'm not sure. Suffice to say I tried a *lot* of things.