# Fineuploader "File is empty" error for every upload above maxConnections

Tags: php, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am getting errors with uploading multiple files. If I set maxConnections to 1, file 2 and further fail. If I set maxConnections to 3, file 4 and further fail. The server response is "File is empty".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
    maxConnections: 1,
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: './upload_bijlagebestanden.php?am_aid=' + document.getElementById("am_aid").value
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570246/fine-uploader-aborting-upload-with-file-is-empty-error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Had to do with Keep-Alive which was switched on with the server upgrade. When I close the connection with header ("Connection: close"); it works fine again. See http://www.bizzeh.com/739/php-problem-with-upload_err_partial-file-upload-error-code-3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any issues like this.  If you are seeing an unexpected server response, you will need to examine your server-side code.  Fine Uploader simply sends the upload requests and waits for your server to respond after processing the file(s).  Most likely, there is some issue with your server-side code or server-side environment.  This is outside of the control and scope of Fine Uploader.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting this answer. The problems started after upgrading php and mysql on the server (both to the latest versions). All settings are the same as before. I was hoping somebody can tell what server side setting can cause this problem.